# background for checkbox at IE

Tags: html, css

I have a list of check-boxes and in IE the last one has strange color. In FF it's perfect.

http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/3987/40401854.jpg

```
<p>
    <span>abc:</span>
    <br /><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="a" name="a" <?php echo $a; ?> /> 1</label>
    <br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="b" name="b" <?php echo $b; ?> /> 2</label>
    <br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="c" name="c" <?php echo $c; ?> /> 3</label>
    <br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="d" name="d" <?php echo $d; ?> /> 4</label>
    <br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="e" name="e" <?php echo $e; ?> /> 5</label>
</p>
```

thank you

Comment: Wow! Thanks for that load of information! /sarcasm

Comment: That is a bizarre use of the `<label>` tag there...  Also, because this issue seems to be related to styles, it would make sense to show us a snippet from your CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Internet Explorer 8, you can press F12 to open a DOM viewer.  Using this tool, you should browse to the checkbox that is giving you trouble and see how its CSS styles are different from the other checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by the PHP code that is being inserted. $1, $2, $3, $4 and $5 aren't valid PHP variables (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php), try to rename them to $v1, $v2 ... $v5.

Comment: they are not numbers. this is just for the example.

Comment: I love examples that generate *different* problems to those which are trying to be solved. It makes debugging so *easy*!

Comment: Then create a reduced test case which actually demonstrates the problem. The PHP will be irrelevant, since it is a client side issue. The CSS, on the other hand, probably is important.

Answer (score 0):

Some CSS things to check: do you have any CSS for id="e"? Or is there a `:last-child` CSS declaration somewhere? Try `overflow:auto` on the parent `p` element (its background color might be showing)?